# Perl Win32::GUI freezes

Tags: perl

I have written a script to connect to a host system and run some commands using the [`Win32::GUI`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aGUI) module for entering commands.

While it is in progress, the GUI freezes and is unresponsive until it is complete.

Could anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: fork/exec or CreateProcess your commands otherwise they will block while the commands run

Comment: Could you post code or links.